# Modify an itab field using where

Tags: abap

How can I write the below code

```
MODIFY git_oi_tab FROM VALUE #( dmbtr = dmbtr * -1 ) 
                    TRANSPORTING dmbtr
                    WHERE shkzg = 'H'.
```

The DMBTR in **dmbtr * -1** is unknown.

Thanks
Elias

PS. I found this but is not what I want as returns the calculated field but clear all others in ITAB it_final_data

```
it_final_data = VALUE #( LET lit_final_data = it_final_data IN FOR lwa_final_data IN lit_final_data  
             ( ovh_ifrs_diff_value = lwa_final_data-ovh_ifrs_value * lv_1st_ledger_amount / sum_OVH_IFRS ) ).
```

Comment: I think I can deduce your question from the code, that would be nice if you explain it with your own words. You can't use MODIFY for that, I don't recommend a constructor expression either. Instead, use a classic LOOP AT.

Answer (score 0):

It appears like you want to invert the sign of the field `DMBTR` in all rows where the field `SHKZG` is equal to `'H'`

In that case you won't get around doing it with a loop:

```
LOOP AT git_oi_tab ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<ls_oi_tab>) WHERE shkzg = 'H'.
     <ls_oi_tab>-dmbtr = <ls_oi_tab>-dmbtr * -1.
ENDLOOP.
```

If you use the `MODIFY itab FROM wa` variant, then `wa` is not constructed separately for each line. It is taken once as-is and applied to all lines. You can't sneak any dynamic logic in there.

Comment: I did this but I am still trying to find a new better way. Thanks Philipp